# Confused by git diff

Tags: git, bitbucket, diff, patch, git-diff

I want to generate a patch file of the differences between my branch and master.  But the branch is quite long-lived so I just did a merge from master to bring it up to date. I can see the differences fine if I start creating a pull request in Bitbucket. But when I do `git diff master..` on my branch I see differences shown that aren't there. Are they resulting from the merge? How can I get a list of differences the same as Bitbucket - just the differences between my branch and master right now?

Comment: If you want to be really explicit you can git diff between any tag or hash. Use `git diff <tag>..<tag2>` or use hashes instead. Use somthing like `git log --decorate --online --graph --all` to see what hashes/tags you want to compare.

Comment: It's not clear which are the commits involved in your pull request, as you mention you've already done a merge yourself. Could you provide some graphical representation of what your repo looks like and which of those commits are the ones involved in the pull request and `git diff`? (`gitk` would work)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## TL;DR

It's not clear to me quite where your confusion starts, but it's worth noting that using `git diff` is quite different from generating a pull request.  Eventually, it will boil down to running `git diff` on the correct specific commits.  The trick lies in *finding* the right commits.

## Long

#### What's in a repository

First, remember what it is that Git keeps.  At a sort of fundamental level, what Git cares about are *source snapshots*, saved in the form of *commits*.  A commit contains a complete snapshot of some source tree.  A commit also contains some *metadata:* name and email addresses of the person, or sometimes two people, who made the commit (*author* and *committer:* they may be the same, or separate) and time-stamps for when they made it; a *parent* commit ID, so that Git can present the series of commits as a history of who (author) did what (see below), and when (timestamp); and a *log message*, to provide the author's description of *why* they did what they did.

Since each commit is a full snapshot, in order to see who actually did what, we must use a command like `git diff`.  Suppose we have two commits done in succession, on branch `master`, like this:

```
(parent)   (child)
df731ac <- 049a12b   <-- master
```

A branch name like `master` lets us find the most recent commit `049a12b`.  We use the child's stored *parent* ID `df731ac` to find the parent, and then we can run `git diff df731ac 049a12b`—or much more simply, `git show master`—to compare `df731ac` to `049a12b`.

Whatever comes up as different here, the author of `049a12b` must have changed it.  But `df731ac` (the predecessor or parent commit) is a complete snapshot, and `049a12b` (the successor or child commit that is the tip of branch `master`) is also a complete snapshot.  Knowing this is helpful for understanding the next part.

Note that, as in the drawing above, a *branch name* like `master` or `develop` or `feature/tall` simply contains the ID of one specific commit.  We call this commit the *tip commit* of the branch.  When you add new commits to a branch, what Git does is create the new commit, which gives it an ID, and then *write the new tip commit ID into the branch name*.  The branch names therefore "move" over time: they always point to the latest (child-most) commit.  Each new commit has, as its parent, the ID that *was* the tip of the branch before, which lets Git follow these backwards pointers through the repository.

If Git commit hash IDs were just one letter, we could draw a simple three-commit repository as:

```
A <-B <-C   <-- master
```

and adding a new commit would simply consist of writing commit `D` with `C` as its parent, and making `master` point to `D`:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master
```

The special name `HEAD` normally contains the *name of a branch*.  So if `HEAD` contains `master`, Git can use `HEAD` to select branch `master`, and `master` to find `D`.  In other words, Git typically *starts* by using a branch name to get a tip commit ID.  Then it looks at that commit to get its parent ID, then looks at the parent commit for another parent, and so forth.  This is what branch names are for, and what they do: they find *tip* commits.

#### Using `git diff`

All `git diff` does (most of the time anyway<sup>1</sup>) is to take *any two individual commits* like this and compare them.  To do this it needs to resolve its two inputs to hash IDs.  Those hash IDs are the two commits; it then compares the two snapshots.

When you run `git diff master..`, Git's `diff` translates `master..` into `master` and `HEAD` (the default to fill in an for empty position around `..` is `HEAD`), and then translates `master` into a branch tip ID.  If the tip commit of branch `master` is `049a12b` as in the drawing above, the hash ID for the left half of the comparison will be `049a12b`.  For the right half, `git diff` must read `HEAD` to get its branch name, such as `develop` or `feature/tall` or whatever.  That branch name then maps to its own tip commit.  Let's say it's abbreviated ID is `6bc9702`.  Then this `git diff` command ultimately tells Git to extract the source snapshot for `049a12b`, the one for `6bc9702`, and compare those two.

You can, however, supply any two hashes for any two commits that you have:

```
git diff 0123456 fedcba9
```

for instance.  But you have to find those commits, or some name that Git will turn into those commits.

(It doesn't matter if you say `git diff A B` or `git diff A..B`; these mean *exactly the same thing*.  This is different from `git log` and most other Git commands: only `git diff` has this special handling for the two-dot `..` syntax.  However, the rule that fills in `HEAD` if one of the names is missing, is common to `git diff` and other Git commands.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Git's `git diff` can produce something called a *combined diff* but these are rather complicated, and not relevant here.

---

#### Brief aside: `git show` and `git log -p`

I mentioned `git show` above.  What `git show` does is to find the parent commit automatically for you, and then show you first the *metadata*—the author (name, email, timestamp) and the log message—and then a diff from parent to child.

When you run `git log -p`, this is similar to running `git show` on each commit, starting from the child-most and working backwards (note that `git log` defaults to starting from `HEAD`).  That is, first `git log` shows you the current branch's tip commit as if by `git show HEAD`, then it shows you that commit's parent as if by `git show`, then it shows you the parent's parent as if by `git show`, and so on.

There is one fairly big difference: `git show` will invoke the special combined diff machinery on any *merge commits*, while `git log` will just show the log message by default, skipping any attempt at diffing the merge.  (There are flags you can use to change this behavior.)

## Pull requests

Pull requests are more complicated, because in order to *make* a pull request, you must either open your repository to someone else who can run `git pull`<sup>2</sup>—this is where the term comes from, and is the original meaning of *pull request*—or else find or create a shared repository, *push* some of your commits to this shared location, and then ask the other person to obtain your commits from the shared location.  I'll ignore the original meaning of "pull request"—essentially just an email message asking someone else to run `git fetch`—and jump into the way these sites handle it instead.

With services like GitHub and Bitbucket, there are now at least *two* other repositories involved.  They even run a trial merge (though this is not so important, other than to verify that the pull request makes sense).  I'm more familiar with GitHub than Bitbucket (I use GitHub myself), but both work the same way here, at least from a sufficiently high level view.

Before you can even think about pull requests, you must "fork" a repository.  A fork is a clone, but with some extra memory about which repository it was *cloned from*.<sup>3</sup>  Behind the scenes, in a way that you normally don't have to care about,<sup>4</sup> the provider does a lot of storage-sharing so that each fork takes very little space on the provider's servers.

This forking, though, is why there are *two* extra repositories involved.  This gives us three repositories we must keep track of:

- Your own Git repository, on your machine.  This is *yours*, to do with as you will.  This is where you run `git diff`, too.
- Your fork of the original repository.  Your machine, and your Git, will refer to this as the `origin` remote.
- The original repository.  This does not necessarily have any name in your repository.  You can—and perhaps should—add another *remote*, which in other examples is called `upstream`.  It's not always required that you add this, but let's assume you did.  If you have not, run:

  ```
  git remote add upstream <url>
  ```

  where  is the URL of the repository you forked your `origin` repository from.

We'll refer, below, to *your* repository, your `origin`, and your `upstream`.  Remember that these remote names are actually just short names in your own repository *referring to* another Git at some URL.  That's what a *remote* is: a short name for a URL where there is a Git repository at that URL.  We'll use the word *provider* to mean GitHub or Bitbucket.

---

<sup>2</sup>The `git pull` command is meant as a short-cut for doing `git fetch` followed by a second Git command, all with one command.  As it turns out, it's often important to use the two commands separately—not always, but often enough that combining them like this was probably a mistake.  Probably, the command now named `git fetch` should have been named `git pull`, and the one now named `git pull` could be options you pass to `git fetch`, or a pair of convenience shortcut commands: `git fm` for fetch-and-merge, and `git fr` for fetch-and-rebase.  I recommend that new Git users avoid `git pull` in favor of the separate commands, at least until they are quite familiar with the separate commands.  Nonetheless, this slight historical error is fully baked into Git today, not only in terms of `git pull` being the obvious (but incorrect) opposite of `git push`, but also in the very name "pull request".

<sup>3</sup>This is over and above—or maybe "beside" is a better description—the way that clones remember their origin through the remote name `origin`.  In any case forks are more like mirror clones initially, but are not slaved to the repository from which they are forked like mirror clones would be.  So they're kind of a hybrid, with extra features—including, specifically, that you can make the service's version of a pull request.

<sup>4</sup>GitHub occasionally brings this up if and when you delete forks vs deleting unforked repositories, since (a) they have to undo the special fork sharing, and (b) deleting forks is safer in that the original (from which you forked) repository is still around.  I imagine Bitbucket is similar.

---

#### A provider pull request starts with `git push`

The main thing to know about `git push` is that it pushes *commits*, not files.  It does this by calling up some other Git repository.  Then it finds out what commits you have that they don't, gives them your commits, and asks them to set some name(s), usually branch names, to remember specific commits.

Now, *your* fork at `origin` belongs to *you*, so you can `git push` to it however and whenever you like.  It's a real, actual Git repository (or something that acts just like one), stored on the provider's machines rather than your own, but it's just like your own Git repository in that it has commits, and branch names, and those branch names point to *tip* commits that point back to previous commits.

When you run `git push`, your request to set a branch name, like `master` or `develop` or `feature/tall`, comes with a commit hash ID.  If their Git doesn't have that commit, your Git gives their Git that commit.  If their Git doesn't have that commit's *parent*, your Git gives their Git the parent, too.  This continues on until you reach some commit their Git *does* have.  Those are what you both shared before you started the `git push`.

The commit hash ID you give them is normally the one at the tip of *your* branch.  So if you have:

```
 ...--H--I--J   <-- master
```

and you `git push origin master`, you are getting your Git to call up their Git and say "I'd like you to set your `master` to commit `J`".  If their Git has their `master` pointing to commit `H`, and is missing `I` and `J`, your Git gives them `I` and `J`, too.

It's possible that their Git has their branch name pointing to some commit you *don't* have, or that isn't in the chain formed by starting from your branch.  Maybe their Git has:

```
...--H--K   <-- master
```

If so, your request, that they add `I` and `J` and make their master remember `J`, will be denied by default, because this would result in:

```
       K   [abandoned]
      /
...--H--I--J   <-- master
```

after which they will "lose" commit `K`, possibly for real and forever.  Since the Git at `origin` belongs to you, though, you can normally use a *force push* (`git push --force`) to turn your polite request into a command: *yes, set your `master` to `J` even though that loses `K`!*  (Usually this is a bad idea and you shouldn't do it.  Instead, you should `git fetch origin` to bring `K` into your own repository, and then either merge or rebase to incorporate `K` along with your own `I--J`.  This gives you a new and different commit, or set of commits, that you *can* push politely, that won't lose `K`.  Instead, they will be pure additions of new commits.)

Note that these changes—usually pure additions of new commits followed by moving a branch name "forward"—go into *your* fork.  They affect your `origin`, but they *do not affect your `upstream`*.  That's not *your* repository after all!  You cannot push directly to your upstream.

#### Finally, the pull request

Instead, what you can do, now that your new commits are in your `origin` which is a fork of your `upstream`, is to make a pull request, typically using some web interface clicky button.  The provider's server will know—you will tell it, if and as necessary—which branch name you want to use in your `origin`, and which branch name you want to use in your `upstream`.

The provider will then notify whoever actually controls the upstream that you have made this pull request.  Since the provider has your fork—your `origin`—specially shared with their repository that is your `upstream`, they will have direct access to the commits you pushed to your branch, that are now at your `origin`'s branch tip.

#### Seeing the diff

Now we have all the tools we need to find the correct diff.  We want to compare *their* branch tip commit, from on the branch name you picked out when you made the pull request, to the tip commit in your `upstream` branch that you set when you ran `git push`.  If you have those two hash IDs in front of you, you can run `git diff <their-upstream-tip-hash> <your-origin-tip-hash>`.

But hash IDs are terribly ugly.  It would be nice if we could get Git to translate for us—and we can.  I skipped over how `git fetch` works above, but let's dive into it for a moment.

#### Using `git fetch`

If you run `git fetch upstream`, that tells your Git to call up the Git that answers at the URL you stored under `upstream`.  That's the Git for the upstream repository at your provider, the one you forked-from.  Your Git will call up that Git, obtain any new commits they have that you don't, and drop them into your repository.  Then—here's the key trick—your Git will set your *remote-tracking branch names* for `upstream` to record the hash IDs for each of their branch tips, per whatever they have right now.

Their `master` becomes your `upstream/master`.  Their `feature/tall` becomes your `upstream/feature/tall`.  Your Git remembers these for you, along with picking up any new commits they have.

The same holds when you run `git fetch origin`: your Git calls up the other Git at `origin`—this is your fork at the provider—and loads up any commits `origin` has that you don't.  Then your Git sets your `origin/master` to remember the `master` at your `origin`, and so on.  Note that when you `git push` to `origin` and give them updates, your Git knows if they *take* the updates.  If they do accept your updates, your Git records the new hash IDs under `origin/master`, `origin/develop`, and so on.

Hence, as long as your Git is in sync with the two Gits at `upstream` and `origin`—and if it isn't you can just run `git fetch` to `upstream` and to `origin` to update it—you now have in your own repository the correct commits, named via `upstream/theirbranch` and `origin/yourbranch`.  So, instead of `git diff <magic hash 1> <magic hash 2>`, if you've sent a pull request asking your upstream to incorporate your `feature/tall` into their `develop`, you can `git diff upstream/develop origin/feature/tall`.

#### Summary

The two commits you need to diff are those in two *other* repositories.  If those two repositories are set up as *remotes* `upstream` and `origin` in your own repository, and your repository is up-to-date with respect to those two repositories, you can `git diff` or `git log` or `git show` the commits in question, and use your remote-tracking names `upstream/*` and `origin/*` to locate specific branch tips.

You can have commits that aren't in *either* of these repositories, and you can see what would happen if you pushed these new commits to your own `origin`.  This allows you to see what would happen if you pushed them and then made a pull request: just compare your `upstream/*` remote-tracking name tip commits to your own branch tip commits.

Comment: Re: `but it's worth noting that using git diff is quite different from generating a pull request.` 
When you start doing a pull request it shows you a "diff" of the changes that will be included, that's what OP is comparing to the output of the `git diff`

Comment: Extraordinarily longwinded answer, the summary gave me what I needed to know! But thanks anyway.

Comment: @parsley72: yeah, sorry about the length - between my confusion about your confusion, and me wanting to figure out how to describe what 3rd party web sites do, the whole thing got a bit out of hand :-)